# model.fit_generator() InvalidArgumentError in VGG for lungs diseases prediction

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an image classification project which is used to predict lungs disease with the help of chest xrays. I would like to fit the model. However, I got error messages.

This is my code for fitting the model.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=5,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)
```

This is the error message:

```
<ipython-input-26-a1bcf5d20df8>:12: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  history = model.fit_generator(
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-a1bcf5d20df8> in <module>
     10 '''
     11 
---> 12 history = model.fit_generator(
     13   training_set,
     14   validation_data=test_set,

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2258         'Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.',
   2259         stacklevel=2)
-> 2260     return self.fit(
   2261         generator,
   2262         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
```

Detected at node 'ArgMax_1' defined at (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in 
app.launch_new_instance()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 149, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in *pseudo_sync_runner
coro.send(None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3057, in run_cell_async
has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async*=asy)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 1, in 
history = model.fit(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 894, in train_step
return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 987, in compute_metrics
self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 501, in update_state
metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 646, in update_state
matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/metrics/metrics.py", line 3295, in categorical_accuracy
return metrics_utils.sparse_categorical_matches(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 887, in sparse_categorical_matches
y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
Node: 'ArgMax_1'
Reduction axis -1 is empty in shape [32,0]
[[{{node ArgMax_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1221]

Can anyone please suggest what should be done?

```
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


# Make sure you provide the same target size as initialied for the image size
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/train",
                                                 target_size=(224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/test",
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')
```

Comment: Any reason you need to use 'model.fit_generator()' function instead of 'model.fit()'?

Comment: model.fit() is not working either

Comment: Please also add the code how you create and compile a model. I would suspect some mismatch for metrics with model output.

Comment: @AndreasKaufmann I have added the code check please

Comment: Please also add the code how you create a model.